# PHP Mailer to outlook: Data not accepted Recipient address reserved by RFC 2606

Tags: php, email, outlook, phpmailer

When i try to send an email to my outlook account I receive an error: SMTP Error: data not accepted. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: 501 5.1.5 Recipient address reserved by RFC 2606 SMTP code: 550 Additional SMTP info: 5.3.4. I tried with my Gmail account and it works but not with outlook live. Anyone can help me?

Here's the code:

```
 <?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                     
$mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'andreacivitas@hotmail.it';       // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '***********';                    // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                             // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('andreacivitas@hotmail.it');
$mail->addAddress('andreacivitas@hotmail.it', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');                        // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


$mail->isHTML(true);                                           // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

[RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) defines some domains that are designated as being for example use only, and are guaranteed never to exist. in particular these include `example.com`, `example.org` and `example.net`. This means that you can use reasonable-looking addressees in example code without fear of inadvertently sending email or other traffic to random people, which might happen if you use a made-up name like `mydomain.com` because it could actually exist.

The error you're seeing has recognised that you're using a reserved domain like this and so is refusing to accept your submission. Use real addresses, or remove the lines that use the reserved addresses, and it will work.

You've set the `SMTPSecure` option incorrectly - it is case-sensitive, so it should be:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

You're disabling certificate verification via `SMTPOptions` - Outlook/Hotmail etc usually serve verifiable certificates, so you should only disable verification to solve a specific problem as it is not a safe way to avoid verification issues, i.e. don't do it unless you *really* need to for a known, specific reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've just chenged all that example.com and it worked. Howevwe I did not change the SMTP Secure because it gave me this error: Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Find out why it's failing. Don't disable verification until you know why, as otherwise you are wasting the security that TLS gives you. It's likely to be either a mismatched certificate name, or your ISP intercepting your traffic.

Comment: Thank you so much, you hit right on the nail. As I am developing, I logged in as admin@example.com. I logged off and then logged in as correct user, it worked.